# Bound all OS processes to one CPU

Tags: linux, process, affinity

Is there a way to limit usage of physical CPU for linux-like OS? 
I do not want to limit CPU number in general I just want to bound all system processes to one CPU and run other soft on others.

Comment: Try for some load balancing software for linux

Answer (score 3):

The builtin utility *taskset* can be used for this given that your box has a motherboard with multiple CPU bays. The oneliner of its man states - "taskset - retrieve or set a process's CPU affinity".

Comment: In addition, the usage of that CPU for a given process can be tweaked with [_cpulimit_](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: So you suggest on system boot bound all running process to one CPU. And than run all other stuff on different ones.

Comment: Hi again. The _taskset_ utility can be used for setting socket and core affinity in-flight, i.e. after a process has been started. So, it is not necessary to do it prior to user-mode. It can be implemented at any point of the bootup process or after user-mode has kicked in. Unfortunately, _taskset_ needs to be run for each process you want executed only on a certain subset of CPU sockets. Please refer to [this link](http://users.sdsc.edu/~glockwood/comp/affinity.php) for a good overview of thread assignments to sockets and cores. Hope that clarifies it a bit more.